# How to play AAC encoded data in UWP?

Tags: audio, visual-c++, uwp, c++-cx, aac

How to play AAC encoded audio data in Memory. UWP samples showing playback using files. playAudio() callback will be called for every 100ms.

```
void AACPlay::playAudio(void *aacData) {
     // To do - play aacData
}
```

Comment: Create an [In​Memory​Random​Access​Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.inmemoryrandomaccessstream).

Comment: That question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Solved the issue by supplying AAC data to [Media​Stream​Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core.mediastreamsource)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by supplying AAC data to [Media​Stream​Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core.mediastreamsource#Windows_Media_Core_MediaStreamSource_SampleRequested). Used [MediaPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer) to play Media​Stream​Sample data.